# Flexslider with Link - using Flexslider Field Collection

Tags: javascript

I am using [Flexslider](https://www.drupal.org/project/flexslider) with [Flexslider Field Collection](https://www.drupal.org/project/flexslider_field_collection).

This is working.

But now I need to include Links for each slide. And only found help when using Views.

Is there a way to include links to each slide without Views?

Answer (score 1):

Just found it:

my Slider-Field-Collection ("field_slide") has:

```
[Label] -[Field Type] - [Widget]
Title- Text - Text field
Body - Long text - Text area
Image - Image - Media file selector
link - Link - Link
```

Display settings:

```
[Field] - [Format]
Image - Image Link Formater - Settings: Link image to: link (field_link)
```

in my content type I use that "field_slide" (embedded) and on display settings: Flexslider

This makes it easy to create content and add unlimited images (as slides) without creating each slide as a node.